# Laravel Access id from url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have url with id.

```
http://localhost/award/public/admin/judge-entries/216/edit
```

I was accessing using

```
 public function edit(Request $request)
 {
      dd($request->input('id'));
 }
```

but it print null value. cant access 216.

Comment: Are you using a resource controller? Or default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how URL parameters work. You should have a route, something like:

```
Route::post("/award/public/admin/judge-entries/{id}/edit", "ExampleController@edit");
```

The `{id}` specifies a URL parameter, and the function handling that route needs to properly access it:

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id){
  dd($id);
}
```

`$request->input()` does not contain URL parameters, so you can't access it via that call, but Laravel translates it to a variable available in the function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

`$request->route('id')` will return the Route Parameter named 'id' by the way.